# How to form a join between character type column and number type column?

Tags: sql

consider the tables below:

employe:

```
------------------------------------
empid ename  dept
------------------------------------
10    vivek  CSE
-------------------------------------
```

salary:

```
----------------------------------------
empid     sal    city
------------------------------------
ten      30,400  hyderabad
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to join these two tables using `employee.empid` (number type) and `salary.empid` (character type).

Can anyone suggest as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: Please read about SQljoins first.You can easily accomplish this task.Following may help you learn joins concept  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Comment: Very bad practice. Will consume too much of time. If you have a table with large number of entries, then you can't even imagine how much time it is gonna take. And secondly, I am not sure, whether this is possible or not.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: ..._why_ is `Salary.empid` stored like this?  What was the reason for this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Firs you should create a table to translate numbers to characters, like 1->one or 10->ten i.e numchar(num int , char char(10)).

```
 Select * from  salary s,Numchar n,employe e
    where s.empid=n.char and n.num=e.empid
```

Organize select list.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. I would really not recommend using english words instead of ints in your database.

But if you must, you must. Several options:

1. I would lean towards adding another column into your salary table which holds the IDs as ints. You can use another language like Java to populate the column. http://www.dzone.com/snippets/convert-integer-english-0. Implementing this same logic directly in SQL would be a pain.
2. Another option which I really do not recommend, is to have a lookup table. Ultimately, this ends up being a very big table just to workaround a bad design. The table could be called int_english and have the fields look like

   `id, english`
   `1 , "one"`
   `2 , "two"`

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the size of the tables and your ability to code in another language or just T-SQL.

But since there is no standard function to convert English numbers to integer numbers, the tedious part of either creating a dictionary or transforming one of your table still need to be done.

I've created a simple dictionary here in T-SQL.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e318/2/0

If performance is an issue, you'd need to look at persisting the data into another table before using it, or optimising the indexes of the original tables - both of which are topics on their own!

If this is one-off solution, then it's fine. If it is long term - consider changing the design of the Salary table so that it uses integers instead of char.

Happy coding.